# Torrent Info hash

Tags: bittorrent

All magnet links I've found contain a 40-byte(char) info hash.

All tracker announce URI's require a 20-byte(char) hash.

How do these translate? Is this the wrong hash?

My goal is to find a peer, using a magnet link, and download 1 byte of data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bittorrent tracker request, format of info\_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072234/bittorrent-tracker-request-format-of-info-hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash used in BitTorrent is SHA-1 and is 160 bits.

The hash in the magnet link is hex-encoded. ie 4 bits per character. 4*40 = 160 bits.

The hash in the announce is raw binary bytes. ie 8 bits per character. 8*20 = 160 bits.
However, as it's not possible to send all raw binary values in a HTTP-get request, the hash gets URL / %percent-encoded and ends up being longer in a variable length, often more than 40 characters.

To translate: Hex-decode the hash from the magnet link to a raw binary string. Then URL-encode the raw binary string if you need to send it in a HTTP-get request.

A raw binary string is not the same as ASCII or UTF. Make sure to deal with it in a safe way in the programming language you use.

Comment: You're right that I was wrong, but many magnet links are base32.

Comment: @harold Yeah, I know. Having been obsolete in more than ten years, they still exists. So most clients supports base32 :/

Comment: So basically convert the base-4 text to base-8 ASCII? I thought Hexadecimal was base-16, is hex different?

Comment: Nevermind me... I was getting very confused, 2^4 == 16

Comment: I've been trying to decode the peers response for like 1 hour. Char codes: `58
4
22
116
26
97
59
33
46
62
26
97
60
123
14
67
26
97
62
107
23
9
26
97
90
21
124
126
26
97
92
0
62
63
26
97
13
98
33
9
26
97
51
105
64
29
26
97
90
49
77
50
26
97
90
61
95
100
26
97
109
0
5
120
26
97
51
35
90
74
...` do you know what encoding is used for this??

Comment: @Tobiq Hard to tell from numbers in decimal form. I think it's better if you make a new question describing in detail how and what you have sent in your request and what you have received back. Preferably in hex+ASCII dump style like [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528682/bittorrent-extension-protocol/43592413#43592413) Wireshark is a good tool to use.